# StyleLint throws error when running in Github action

Tags: javascript, json, stylelint, scss-lint

I have been trying to deep dive into the problem, but I cannot figure out where everything is going wrong. As you can see below is where the error is happening for this specific rule https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/declaration-block-no-redundant-longhand-properties/. Any advice and help would be greatly appreciated :).

```
node_modules/stylelint/lib/rules/declaration-block-no-redundant-longhand-properties/index.js:117
                            .map((p) => transformedDeclarationNodes.get(p)?.value.trim())
                                                                           ^
```

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

my linter config file

```json
{
  "extends": "stylelint-config-recommended-scss",
  "plugins":["stylelint-prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": true,
    "scss/dollar-variable-pattern": null,
    "block-no-empty": null,
    "rule-empty-line-before":["always",{"ignore":["first-nested"]}],
    "scss/selector-no-redundant-nesting-selector": true,
    "font-family-no-missing-generic-family-keyword": [true,{"ignoreFontFamilies":["MAIN_THEME"]}],
    "color-function-notation": "legacy",
    "alpha-value-notation": "number",
    "scss/dollar-variable-colon-space-after": "always",
    "scss/dollar-variable-colon-space-before": "never",
    "unit-allowed-list": ["px","vmin","em","rem","deg","%","vh","vw","s"],
    "declaration-block-no-redundant-longhand-properties":[true, {
      "severity": "warning"
    }],
    "selector-class-pattern": "^.*$",
    "number-max-precision":2,
    "keyframes-name-pattern": "^[a-zA-Z]+?(?:-+[a-zA-Z]{2,10}){1,3}$"
  }
}
```

my CI action file

```yaml
name: something
on: [pull_request]

jobs:
  buildnode:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: '12.x'

    - name: install modules
      run: npm install

    - name: run scss linter
      run: npm run styleLinter

    - name: run js linter
      run: npm run linter

    - name: build web app
      run: npm run build

    - name: test the code
      run: npm test
```

Answer (score 0):

Node version is out of date for styleLint so I updated to 18 that resolved the  issue.